# AlarmManager not correct work

Tags: java, android, notifications

i want get date and time from user with TimePickerDialog and DatePicker and then show notification at time When the user has chosen but notification shows at current time

get Time :

```
 TimePickerDialog tpd=new TimePickerDialog(AddTaskActivity.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                    Model_Static.bol_time=true;
                    hourFinal=view.getCurrentHour();
                    MinuteFinal=view.getCurrentMinute();

                    tv4.setText(hourOfDay+":"+minute);
                }
            },hour,minute,true);
            tpd.show();
```

get year Month and Day:

```
  btn_sbt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Model_Static.bol_tarikh=true;
                    Calendar cal=pdp.getDisplayPersianDate();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),cal.getTimeInMillis()+"",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    yearFinal=cal.getTime().getYear();
                    monthFinal=cal.getTime().getMonth();
                    dayFinal=cal.getTime().getDay();
```

set AlarmManager :

```
                        if (Model_Static.bol_tarikh&&Model_Static.bol_time)
                        {

                            intent123.putExtra("id",2);
                            pendingIntent123=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),2,intent123,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                            Calendar calcal=Calendar.getInstance();

                            calcal.set(Calendar.YEAR,yearFinal);
                            calcal.set(Calendar.MONTH,monthFinal);
                            calcal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,dayFinal);
                            calcal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,hourFinal);
                            calcal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,MinuteFinal);
                            long b=calcal.getTimeInMillis();



                            am123.set(AlarmManager.RTC,b,pendingIntent123);
```

Comment: You should really try to debug your code first, before sending a question to SO. Set some breakpoints, step through your code, look how your variables change before reaching  the line `am123.set(AlarmManager.RTC,b,pendingIntent123);`

Answer (score 0):

It's really hard to understand what is not working.. you should debug it line by line but here some points you should consider:

First of all check if your manifest contain this line:

<
 receiver android:name=".NotificatonReceiver"/ >

Where .NotificationReciver is the class where you catch the alarm broudcast.
In addition make sure that your Reciver indeed implements BrodcastReciver.

Hope that helped